# AutoValue not finding generated constructor in Android project

Tags: android, auto-value

I am struggling to get [AutoValue](https://github.com/google/auto/tree/master/value) working in an Android project. It seems to be working for others, so I must just be missing something. I've tried enabling the jack compiler, that didn't seem to help.

[Here](https://github.com/srsudar/GithubHotness) is a demo project that fails when I build it locally. The complaint is in [this class](https://github.com/srsudar/GithubHotness/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/cse390/githubhotness/models/Repo.java#L21), where it can't find the `AutoValue_Repo` constructor.

Here is my project level `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.1'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And there is my module level `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "org.cse390.githubhotness"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })

    provided 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2-rc1'
    compile "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2-rc1"
    apt "com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.2-rc1"

    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'

    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Here is the class that isn't being auto-valued:

```
@AutoValue
public abstract class Repo {
  public abstract int id();
  public abstract String name();
  public abstract String fullName();
  public abstract String description();
  public abstract int numStars();
  public abstract String language();
  public abstract String htmlUrl();

  static Repo create(int id, String name, String fullName, String description,
                     int numStars, String language, String htmlUrl) {
    // See "How do I...?" below for nested classes.
    return new AutoValue_Repo(id, name, fullName, description, numStars,
        language, htmlUrl);
  }

}
```

Any obvious mistakes here?

Comment: Because the class is being generated access to the create method must be public autovalue can work.

Comment: Of all the things I tried (including changing visibility of the class and the member variables), I apparently neglected to try that. But indeed it works. If you promote your comment to an answer I'll accept it. I should also note, in Android Studio if I fiddle with the visibility of the static method I have to manually invoke a make for it to pick up errors or fix errors. This may have hidden this fix from me previously, though I can't swear to it. Thank you!

Comment: Im glad I could help. Ive had similar problems before with dagger generating class. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because we are generating a class here access to the method needs to be public so autovalue can work.

```
  public static Repo create(int id, String name, String fullName, String description,
                 int numStars, String language, String htmlUrl) {
        // See "How do I...?" below for nested classes.
        return new AutoValue_Repo(id, name, fullName, description, numStars,
                    language, htmlUrl);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I forgot to set `@AutoValue` above class description. Also the class should be external, not inner.